# Integration with LAMP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, apache, mamp

Please excuse my stupidity here as I've just started with Yeoman but I have a general question regarding increasing a project beyond the scaffolding stage and integrating it with PHP - and Apache.

Obviously the Node.js server doesn't run PHP scripts and when I try and open the same project from my Apache (MAMP) server (I've tried '/', '/app' and '/dist' directories) the pages just hang and eventually timeout. I'm not entirely sure why though?  Is it possible to get the same project working on both Apache and NodeJS.

An ideal solution would be if Node.js could run PHP but not sure if this will ever happen.

I might be going down the wrong route entirely here...

Thanks!

Comment: @pythonian29033 `> Is it possible to get the same project working on both Apache and NodeJS` is not a stupid question.

Comment: @pythonian29033 did you wake up on the wrong side of the bed this morning?! You're assuming I'm stupid for not asking as many questions as you. Most of the time I Google or figure things out for myself. Read the question like fardjad did as it's not an open-ended question.

Comment: @fardjad - do you have any examples of reverse-proxy with node.js or any further information?

Thanks!

Comment: @AndyMeek Take a look at [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). The examples should give you an idea how to implement such thing.

Comment: @fardjad Ok, thanks. I found a tutorial [link] http://dvisagie.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/running-nodejs-alongside-apache.html but this only seems to allow the node.js to be ran from a folder (in  this case http://127.0.0.1/node) rather than having everything running together. I've learned something new anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want to do, is to make a [reverse-proxy](/questions/tagged/reverse-proxy) with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

You'll need to define some routes in your **node.js** application, so it will (directly) respond to client requests or pipes them to the [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) server according to request headers (ex. URL or hostname.)